# Slick slider covers the burger menu

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I am sorry to bother you guys but I am a complete newbie and helping my parents to make a website but I don't know what to do.

I am using  the "slick slider" and a burger menu (appears under 1000px wide), but the slider is above the burger menu and I don't what what to do!

The code is relatively big and I am not sure which parts to post, so the best thing I can do is just to send the link to the temporary host and send the files :(
I Hope that someone can help
http://f0646775.xsph.ru/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put a z-index on your code to show it above the slider.This should work.

```css
.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition-duration: .25s;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, tried putting it everywhere :(
Thanks for answering!

Comment: you are not gonna put it everywhere. you need to put it on the class .menu__box try to make it higher like z-index:10; and put !important in it.

Comment: on your burger.css you'll find the class .menu__box line 60 that's where you should put that z-index:10 !important;